# Fixing loose crank handle for casement window

Tags: windows

I have a casement window where the crank was rotated while the window was locked shut. As a result, the crank is loose and falls downward when the window is in a closed position.

In the picture, the crank should be tight and resting where the grey putty is in closed position but instead falls downward more.

[image]

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a setscrew under the handle that can be tightened down to improve the handle's grip on the mechanism.

Comment: In addition, the shaft is usually splined. If part of the mechanism was bent when the handle was forced you could either try to correct the bend (unlikely) or just R/R the handle using the best spline match for the desired parking position.

Comment: The splines can also wear out if people keep cranking the handle when it's loose enough to slip. Once it reaches that point, tightening the setscrew may not be enough.